# Getting xml from ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, xml, ckeditor, ckeditor5

How do I get the output from ckeditor as XML instead of HTML?

I thought I could just use 
`editor.data.processor=new XmlDataProcessor();` but that only seems to work for input where the editor now requires XML when calling `editor.setData()` but `editor.getData()` still returns HTML, instead of XML. The data is not contained in a root element, and `<img>` tags are not closed.

The `toData` method which should convert to XML, is implemented as follows which doesn't look like something which could ever work since it tries to use `_htmlWriter` to convert to XML. So it just looks like a feature nobody ever implemented.

```
toData( viewFragment ) {
    // Convert view DocumentFragment to DOM DocumentFragment.
    const domFragment = this._domConverter.viewToDom( viewFragment, document );

    // Convert DOM DocumentFragment to XML output.
    // There is no need to use dedicated for XML serializing method because BasicHtmlWriter works well in this case.
    return this._htmlWriter.getHtml( domFragment );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using toData/toView? https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_dataprocessor_xmldataprocessor-XmlDataProcessor.html

Comment: @DipenShah That don't work either. It just returns html(See my edit). I guess the issue is simply that the code to convert to xml have not been written so I will fill a bug repport now

Comment: it had been written: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/blob/master/src/dataprocessor/xmldataprocessor.js ...while it might be lacking in the CDN build. building from source should be the answer here.

Comment: Yes the class exists, but the one on github still uses this._htmlWriter.getHtml( domFragment ) to "convert" data to xml, and that don't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not aware of a [CKEditor 5 method for getting data](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/saving-data.html) that outputs XML. However, a potential workaround would be to convert the HTML output to XML using [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer)

For example (the `node` variable is used below for convenience since `XMLSerializer` requires a [DOM Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) as input rather than a HTML string):

```js
const node = document.createElement('div');
ClassicEditor
  .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
  .then((editor) => {
    editor.ui.focusTracker.on('change:isFocused', (event, name, value) => {
      if (!value) {
        const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        node.innerHTML = editor.getData();
        console.log(serializer.serializeToString(node));
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div>Enter something and click outside the CKEditor to view the xml string in the console</div>
<textarea name="content" id="editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, did not think about just doing the conversion my self. Only slight problem is that XMLSerializer is buggy on Safari(Mac OS X) where it leaves &nbsp; in the result. But nothing a string replace can't fix.